Retrieve SMS from a SIM card in SIM7600G-H 4G HAT in Python
Update: I changed timeout=1 to timeout=5 and once the script started to run, sent a message to the SIM card immediately. Then I got all the messages. When I restarted the Pi and switched timeout=1, and re-run the script, this time I was not sending any messages, and I still can retrieve all messages from the SIM card. Then I tested it as a function in a larger Python script where the retrieved message is used as the return of the function. This time nothing came out. And when I test the original script (which worked well before testing in the larger script), it couldn't retrieve anything again.
Original Post:
I am trying to make a remote controller. Attach a SIM7600G-H 4G HAT on Raspberry Pi 4, and a SIM card is inserted into the 4G HAT. I followed lots of instructions to retrieve the message received by the SIM card, but nothing comes out at the step of ser.read().
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',115200, timeout=1)

ser.write(b'AT+CMGF=1\r\n')
time.sleep(1)
ser.write(b'AT+CMGL="ALL"\r\n') 
time.sleep(1)
response = ser.read().decode()
print(response)  # ---------nothing is printed.

When running the Python script, in minicom, I get:
AT+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CMGL="ALL"
+CMGL: 0; "REC 
READ","+1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","24/04/19, 
xx:xx:xx-xx"
TEST1
+CMGL: 0; "REC 
READ","+1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","24/04/19, 
xx:xx:xx-xx"
TEST2
+CMGL: 0; "REC 
READ","+1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","24/04/19, 
xx:xx:xx-xx"
TEST3

OK

Anyone know why the ser.read() won't get anything?
My expectation is to be able to retrieve SMS messages from a SIM card by a Python script.

I don't have experience with this specifically, but maybe you need to do a flush: ser.flush() after writing and before sleeping.  Also (if that doesn't fix it) can you clarify the 'minicom' text you included.  Did you mean to say that you are pasting in a session where you talked to the modem directly using minicom and that (when talking directly) you had success?  Also, if minicom is working for you, maybe provide your full command line for that so we can double check other details like flow control, etc

ser.flush() didn't help.  In the terminal, by typing: minicom -D /dev/ttyS0, we will be able to communicate with the port. All the operations on the port will be displayed. AT+CMGF=1, AT+CMGL="ALL", AT+CMGR=1, all works in the terminal. But won't work in Python.

When Python script is running, the terminal will automatically show the operations (here are the AT commands) and results triggered by the Python code.

time.sleep(1) Please never do this as a substitute for reading and parsing the response from the modem.

Any difference with just ser.read() instead of ser.read().decode()?

@Helen, can you please update your question to show the way that you are using the ser.flush() command?

@hlovdal, so what should I use? All empty with/without .decode(). When I am able to retrieve the msg, without .decode() gave me strings starting with b'.

@BillHuneke I kind of figured out a way, but still have issues. Please see the updates.

be sure to read the API docs for the commands you are using (e.g. Serial.read(), Serial.write(), etc).  In the case of 'read', I see that the default behavior is that it reads only one byte (which would explain why you are not seeing anything printed out most of the time).  I agree with @hlovdal that using sleep is the kind of workaround which will only bite you again later (and will be even more frustrating to find later).  You should probably read some other posts about other people using this with Python  (ie, search for "python CMGF" for example). See hlovdal's other posts :)
